# Search an entire array for a value within a for loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I'm PLSQL programming and now I'm learning Python. I want to code a simple for loop and print a value if the condition is true. But How can I search a entire array? Do you have any idea? Thanks

```
v_names = ['Gustavo', 'Tim', 'Matt', 'Bjorn', 'Lars']

for names in v_names:
    if names[x] == 'Gustavo': #wrong code line, I need your help here
        print ('You have a great name!')
```

Comment: Remove `[x]` (and maybe rename `names` to `name` for clarity).

Comment: just use `if names == ` instead of  `if names[x] == `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if "Gustavo" in v_names:
    print("You have a great name!")
```

Comment: my god! You can search a entire array list using a simple if sentence??? Im facinated how simple is Python!!! i will mark your answer as correct soon

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you want but does this do the job?

```
v_names =  ['Gustavo', 'Tim', 'Matt', 'Bjorn', 'Lars']

for name in v_names: #This loops over every element in v_names 
    if name == 'Gustavo': #Now if name is equal to Gustavo
        print ('You have a great name!') #Then print stuff.
```